# Django custom model manager for derived class - filtering on base class attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I am using Django 3.2

I have the following models:

```
class AuthoriseableApprovedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(AuthoriseablePendingManager, self).get_queryset().filter(computed_status=AUTHORISATION_STATUS_APPROVED)



class Authorisable(models.Model):
    # various fields ...
    approved_objects = AuthoriseableApprovedManager()

class ApprovedPublishedArticlesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.approved_objects.filter(is_published=True)
    
    
    
class Article(Authorisable, 
              # Other base classes
              ):
    
    # various fields
    # ....

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    
    approved_published_articles = ApprovedPublishedArticlesManager()
    
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at', )
```

I have the following code in my views.py

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.approved_published_articles.all()  # <- Barfs here ...
```

I get the error message:

> 'ApprovedPublishedArticlesManager' object has no attribute 'approved_objects'

Which makes sense, since `ApprovedPublishedArticlesManager` does not derive from `Authorisable`.

How do I create a custom manager that allows me to filter based on base class properties - does my custom manager have to derive from `models.Manager` and the relevant base class (`Authorisable` in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `.get_queryset(…)` method of your `ApprovedPubhishedArtcilesManager`. You can access the model with:

```
class ApprovedPublishedArticlesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.approved_objects.filter(is_published=True)
```

although it might be better to inherit from `AuthoriseableApprovedManager` and make use of the base implementation of the `.get_queryset(…)` method. This is also more robust, since you do not have to take into account for what name that manager will be registered.